# Importer fails to import every post

Tags: database, import, export

I'm trying to move the content of a wordpress.com blog to a self-hosted one. Right now I'm just trying to set things up on my local environment.

I exported the content using the built-in WordPress exporter from the original blog and the file is a little bigger than 2 megabytes. Anyway I managed to increase the upload limit so the import is actually working. The problem is that it imports just the posts of 2010.

Is there some other limit set somewhere else?

Comment: Try to import table by table instead the whole database at once. You'll less likely to hit some memory limit. 2 Meg is small, but it depends also on hosting.

Comment: How did you export the *database* from a wordpress.com account? Or, do you mean that you exported the *content*, using the built-in WordPress exporter?

Comment: ok, my mistake. I exported the content using the built-in WordPress exporter. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I exported again the whole content, choosing to export the posts separately. This resulted in a much bigger file (almost 8 megabytes) and it seems it contains all posts I wrote in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Open the WXR in a text editor and see if it contains posts from later years. If not, you will need to revisit your export settings from WP.com to make sure you're pulling all posts.

If it does contain posts from these years, there might be a non UTF8 character breaking the import. You should be able to spot any offending characters in a typical IDE that parses XML. If this is the case, you should edit those characters and retry the import.

Comment: well, I thought there were later posts, since trying to search for some words of the post I fount them. Now I see that there are just the urls of recent posts and o actual content. I don't get it. And anyway there aren't so many options in the exporter. Not sure what can I do

Comment: Check out my site from my profile and email me a link to your WXR there. I'll look it over and do a test import on my machine. I'll update my answer if I figure it out.

Comment: thanks for your offer. I managed to make it work. I exported the content again, this time choosing the "articles only" options and it gave me a much bigger file with the right content in it.

Comment: @Carlo Can you post your resolution as an answer to help others in the community? Thanks!

Comment: ok, sure. I didn't think about it : )